# Spark(1.6) Densevector.type does not take parameters

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I'm following along with this article:

http://learningfrombigdata.com/semantic-similarity-between-sentences-using-apache-spark/

However, when i get to this part:

```
def distance(lvec: String, rvec: String): Double = {
    val l = DenseVector(lvec.split(',').map(_.toDouble))
    val r = DenseVector(rvec.split(',').map(_.toDouble))
    math.sqrt(sum((l - r) :* (l - r)))
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Name: Compile Error
Message: <console>:177: error: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.DenseVector.type does not take parameters
           val l = DenseVector(lvec.split(',').map(_.toDouble))
                              ^
<console>:178: error: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.DenseVector.type does not take parameters
           val r = DenseVector(rvec.split(',').map(_.toDouble))
```

I suspect that it might have something to do with versions (I'm using Spark 1.6.0), but i am not sure, and was unable to find much information about this error online, would appreciate any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing `new`:

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.DenseVector
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.DenseVector

scala> new DenseVector(Array(1, 2, 3))
res1: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.DenseVector = [1.0,2.0,3.0]
```